# How to replace null values in the output of a left join operation with 0 in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple PySpark dataframe, df1-

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", 1),
    ("u1", 2),
    ("u2", 3),
    ("u3", 4),

    ],
    ['user_id', 'var1'])

print(df1.printSchema())
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Output-

```
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: long (nullable = true)

None
+-------+----+
|user_id|var1|
+-------+----+
|u1     |1   |
|u1     |2   |
|u2     |3   |
|u3     |4   |
+-------+----+
```

I have another PySpark dataframe df2-

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'f1'),
    (2, 'f2'),

    ],
    ['var1', 'var2'])

print(df2.printSchema())
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Output-

```
root
 |-- var1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- var2: string (nullable = true)

None
+----+----+
|var1|var2|
+----+----+
|1   |f1  |
|2   |f2  |
+----+----+
```

I have to join the two dataframes mentioned above, by using a left-join operation on them-

```
df1.join(df2, df1.var1==df2.var1, 'left').show()
```

Output-

```
+-------+----+----+----+
|user_id|var1|var1|var2|
+-------+----+----+----+
|     u1|   1|   1|  f1|
|     u1|   2|   2|  f2|
|     u2|   3|null|null|
|     u3|   4|null|null|
+-------+----+----+----+
```

But as you can see, I am getting null values in the rows for which there two tables don't have a match.
How can I replace all the null values with 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fillna`. Two fillnas are needed to account for integer and string columns.

```
df1.join(df2, df1.var1==df2.var1, 'left').fillna(0).fillna("0")
```

Comment: i have already tried this solution. But it does not seem to be working for me. I am not sure why is it so.

Comment: @n0obcoder does having two fillnas work...?

Comment: yes it did work. But why are two fillnas working? and why is zero a string here?

Comment: @n0obcoder that's because `var2` column is of string type. It cannot be filled with an integer 0, but only with a string "0".

Comment: so if i use .fillna(0).fillna("0"), then all the null values from any given column will be replaced by 0, right? its just that some 0 will be int, and some will be str, depending on the datatype of the column. am i correct?

Comment: If you have columns that are not numeric/string (e.g. array/struct/map) then they will not be filled.

Comment: or boolean too, to be complete

Comment: ok, is there any way of using the filter method and in order to get all the rows for which a given column has null value in it?

Comment: `df.filter(df['col'].isNull())`

Comment: and how can I fill columns with array datatype?

Comment: you'll need to use `coalesce` because `fillna` does not support array.

Answer (score 5):

You can rename columns after `join` (otherwise you get columns with the same name) and use a dictionary to specify how you want to fill missing values:

```
f1.join(df2, df1.var1 == df2.var1, 'left').select(
    *[df1['user_id'], df1['var1'], df2['var1'].alias('df2_var1'), df2['var2'].alias('df2_var2')]
).fillna({'df2_var1': 0, 'df2_var2': '0'}).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+----+--------+--------+
|user_id|var1|df2_var1|df2_var2|
+-------+----+--------+--------+
|     u1|   1|       1|      f1|
|     u2|   3|       0|       0|
|     u1|   2|       2|      f2|
|     u3|   4|       0|       0|
+-------+----+--------+--------+
```